# Removing everything except the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 from a file

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

I want to remove everything from a file, such that only the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 remain. Line breaks should be kept. How can I delete everything else from the file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
sed -i 's/[^1-5]//g' file
```

Here's a small test:

```
$ echo $'ab129c\n1d3e5fqq9cm3275\ncn730m271nv05482m1'
ab129c
1d3e5fqq9cm3275
cn730m271nv05482m1
$ echo $'ab129c\n1d3e5fqq9cm3275\ncn730m271nv05482m1'|sed 's/[^1-5]//g'
12
135325
3215421
```

Answer (score 3):

`tr` should be more efficient than `sed`.  Copying icyrock's test:

```
$ echo $'ab129c\n1d3e5fqq9cm3275\ncn730m271nv05482m1' | tr -dc "1-5\n"
12
135325
3215421
```

There's one disadvantage to `tr`, though: it can't do an in-place edit of an existing file (like `sed -i` does); if that's what you want you'd have to write to a temp file, then replace the original with that:

```
tr -dc "1-5\n" <file.txt >tempfile.txt && mv tempfile.txt file.txt
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning tr (though I consider myself advanced linux user, I don't remeber seeing it anywhere).

Answer (score 1):

I did it with:

```
sed -r 's/[^12345]//g' <file>
```

That will dump it to screen, and you can write to a file with:

```
sed -r 's/[^12345]//g' <file> > <new_file>
```

Or you could edit the file directly with

```
sed -i -r 's/[^12345]//g' <file>
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw yours did it without it. I tend to use it any time I'm using regex, even when it's simple enough to not need the full regex capabilities. I don't think it does any harm, it just isn't needed.

Comment: `alias sedr="sed -r"` :) Agree it's much easier to use with `-r` in many situations.